# Включение стилей в компоненте-наследнике

Tags: css, vue.js, scss

Есть компонент `App.vue`. Внутри него объявлен стиль `scss`:

```
.roboto-text {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Разметка:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
      <div>
        <Head/>
      </div>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Есть компонент `Head.vue`. Я хочу сделать `extened` этого стиля внутри него:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">

    .user-info {
        padding-top: 0;
        @extened .roboto-text;
    }
</style>
```

Этот стиль не экстендится. Почему?

Ошибка:

````
SassError: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .roboto-text !optional" to avoid this error.
    ╷
106 │     @extend .roboto-text;
    │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  /home/eurvanov/vuejs/adeo-dataplatform-dictionaries/src/components/Menu.vue 106:5  root stylesheet

 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--18-0!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Menu.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=9bcc0be2&scoped=true&lang=scss& 4:14-518 14:3-18:5 15:22-526
 @ ./src/components/Menu.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=9bcc0be2&scoped=true&lang=scss&
 @ ./src/components/Menu.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--18-0!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.68:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js```
````

Comment: скорее всего проблема в `scoped`, в этом случае стили должны ограничиваться компонентом, тут у тебя два компонента - они никак не связаны, вот и не может найти класс из второго компонента

Comment: @Grundy нет это никак не связано.

Comment: Пробовал.......

Comment: чего пробовал-то? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Общий ответ на вопрос.

В Vue на данный момент **нет** достаточно удобного способа наследовать стили. Самым простым обходным решением является использование *миксинов*. Создайте отдельный `.scss` файл. Поместите туда стили из `.roboto-text`, импортируйте этот файл и через `@include` добавляйте стили.

#### mixins.scss

```
@mixin roboto-text {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

#### Parent.vue

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
    @import "mixins.scss";

    .some-class {
        @include roboto-text;
    }
</style>
```

#### Child.vue

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
    @import "mixins.scss";

    .other-class {
        @include roboto-text;
    }
</style>
```

**mixins.scss можно импортировать глобально**. Это скорее всего будет масимально не очевидно для вашей IDE но *вы сможете использовать миксины не импортируя их.*

Для этого нужно создать `vue.config.js` файл.

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      // передать параметры для sass-loader
      sass: {
        // @/ алиас для src/
        // строка ниже будет интерпритированна как `src/variables.scss`
        // при сборке проекта, вначале эта строка будет добавлена во 
        // все style в SFC (Single File Component). А затем скомпилированна SCSS.
        data: `@import "@/mixins.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Источник: [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/Haixiang6123/353aeb752d2f45b30b3856dfcf5c2718#file-01172019-visfg-vurcli-js)

### Мнение конкретно по Вашему случаю.

Для глобальных настроек (например основной шрифт). Можно поместить в **не** scoped стили в `App.vue`.

```
<style lang="scss">
    // стили которые будут доступны во всем проекте.
</style>

<style scoped lang="scss">
    // стили которые будут доступны только внутри данного компонента.
</style>
```